# Django ModelChoiceField, label_from_instance object iteration

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

The method **label_from_instance** from **CustomModelChoiceField**, 
iterates one object at a time, but I need the method to receive all objects at once.

This is due to a freight calculation call that waits for all objects at once for the calculation.

Is it possible?

```py
    from django import forms
    from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

    class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
        def label_from_instance(self, obj):
            return mark_safe("My Object custom label <strong>%i</strong>" % obj.id)


    class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
        my_field = CustomModelChoiceField(label=_('The form label'), queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(), widget=forms.RadioSelect, empty_label=None)
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the queryset with the calculated freight value then use the new attribute in your `label_from_instance()` method.

Comment: if I annotate for example: MyModel.objects.all().annotate(price=15), I will get a error, because I will not have this value em table.